# How variable are assigned in a function call?

Tags: c++, c, function-calls

```
void fun(int b1[]){}
int main()
{
    int a1[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int b[]=a1; //error
    fun(a1);// works fine

}
```

how is b1 assigned to a1?. Why is it not same as `int b[]=a1;`?

Comment: You can't do what you are doing. int *b = a1

Comment: `b[]` as a function parameter  is treated as a pointer simply without checking the size of the array. Address of the array `a1` is converted to a pointer when it is passed as a parameter.